# Error LNK2028: Thrown when instantiating an native C++ class within C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

Currently I'm working on a solution that contains a C++/CLI project (which is a wrapper of a native C++ dll) and a C# WPF project (which uses the functionality of the C++/CLI wrapper).

The problem I have is that when a pointer to a native class is instantiated (within the wrapper) a linker error occurs.

Class:

```
public ref class MCBiosUpdate
{
public:
    MCBiosUpdate(void);
    MCBiosUpdate(MCBiosUpdate^);
    MCBiosUpdate(CBIOSUpdate&);
    ~MCBiosUpdate(void);
    !MCBiosUpdate(void);

private:
    CBIOSUpdate *pBiosUpdate;      //Native C++ Class
};
```

Code that causes error:

```
MCBiosUpdate::MCBiosUpdate(void) : pBiosUpdate(new CBIOSUpdate)   //error LNK2028
{
}
```

Output:

> 1>MCBiosUpdate.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000E)
>   "public: __thiscall CBIOSUpdate::~CBIOSUpdate(void)"
>   (??1CBIOSUpdate@@$$FQAE@XZ)

1. How can I resolve the linker error so that the program runs as intended?
2. What causes this linker error?
3. If there is any improvements to the code or any suggestions to help me resolve the problem; feel free to comment.

Comment: That error isn't caused by that statement you quoted.  But otherwise it fits the code.  The linker just says that it can't find the implementation of the destructor of the CBIOSUpdate class.  Easy mistake, declaring one but forgetting to define it.  Or link it.

Comment: Yes, the linker could not find the implementation of the destructor because I didn't export it within the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`What causes this linker error?`

Reason could be `pBiosUpdate` interface is not exported from the DLL to be visible to the DLL'S clients, in your case the C# code.

`How can I resolve the linker error so that the program runs as intended?`

1. use `dllexport` as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

(or)

1. Use a module definition file (`.def file`) to export the DLL's function as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Spot on... The destructor was not exported within the DLL.